# Это мой фотографа успех.

Tags: оборот

Возможен ли такой оборот (см. заголовок), если да, то как называется сей оборот и выделяется ли запятыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Это мой фотографа успех". Такой оборот речи возможен, знаки препинания не нужны.

Здесь применен  особый прием художественной выразительности - инверсия.

Инверсия - это нарушение общепринятой грамматической последовательности речи, перестановка частей фразы, придающая ей особую выразительность.Этот прием часто применяется в поэзии:

Любви, надежды, тихой славы Недолго нежил нас обман (А. С. Пушкин).

И девы песнь едва слышна Долины в тишине глубокой (А.С.Пушкин).

Comment: Мне кажется, приведённые вами примеры не совсем здесь подходят. Я бы поставил тире посля "мой". Правил постановки тире достаточно много, чтобы в них запутаться, но главное одно - тире помогает сделать текст болеее выразительным, как в данном случае:"Это мой - фотографа успех". Ещё и восклицательный знак в конце не помешает.Пример: "Ты – гнида меня – боевого командира в предатели!?"

Comment: Думаю, что вариант с тире не подойдет, здесь интонация другая. Первое тоническое (и логическое) ударение падает  на слово "фотографа": Это мой фотОграфа (повышение тона) успЕх (понижение тона). И на письме авторское тире только всех запутает, а не прояснит картину.

Comment: Да, София, вероятнее всего вы правы, я оченьнь ценю ваше мнение, но в этой стуации останусь при своём.

Comment: Всё-таки попробую убедить Вас изменить ваше мнение.«Это мой успех в качестве фотографа» - это содержание надо представить в виде слогана. Пока длинно, невыразительно, стиль книжный.  Сокращаем фразу: «Это мой успЕх (пауза) фотОграфа» - тоже не звучит, да и грамматика сомнительная. (На слове «фотографа» делается естественное понижение тона, которое ничем не выделяет это слово). А теперь делаем инверсию: «Это мой  фотОграфа (пауза) успЕх». Теперь слово «фотОграфа» становится логическим центром высказывания, и грамматика в глаза не бросается. Слоган готов: краткий, выразительный, энергичный.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, "фотограф" должен быть выделен запятыми. Это мой успех, успех фотографа. К примеру: "Это наш, запорожских казаков, ответ тебе, султан". "Это мой, фотографа, успех". Разве это не однотипные предложения"?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что он фотограф? Может быть, это и не профессия его, а просто увлечение. Может быть, он артист, депутат или еще кто. Просто он хочет сказать, что в данном случае он успешен именно как фотограф. А ваше обособление отождествляет его с фотографом, при этом правильность грамматической конструкции вызывает большие сомнения. А вот казаки являются только казаками - это их постоянный признак.

Comment: Логично! Но: "Это наш, советских рабочих, ответ Вам, Чемберлен!" Считаете, что "рабочий" - это постоянный признак? Но ответ Чемберлену писали в ЦК ВКП(б), вовсе не рабочие!